# Matching <script> or <iframe onload in querystring

Tags: isapi, isapi-rewrite

i am facing xxs problem and i am using ISAPI Rewite 3. I want to detect if a querystring contains ... or   redirect it to my home page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following structure:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*iframe.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think the condition doesn't need the start/end if you're adding the .*. Isn't just `iframe` enough? And he script also, so I think this is enough `(iframe|script)`

Comment: The comment got away from me. The parentheses aren't even needed: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} iframe|script`